# Records not being formed upon clicking of button from VF Page

Tags: create-records

```
for(CountrywiseAggregration__c cWA :[Select Country__c,Year__c , cWA.PDPAllocationafterFXQ1__c 
                                       from CountrywiseAggregration__c 
                                       where Country__c!=null and 
                                             Year__c = : year 
                                       ORDER BY Country__c]){
                cWA.PDPAllocationafterFXQ1__c = 0.0;
                mapCountryWiseAggr.put(cWA.Country__c,cWA);
            }       
    }
```

Here we are  instantiating the object and querying 'n' number of fields and initializing the numerical fields to zero.

And later based on some some conditions values are being assigned to cWA.PDPAllocationafterFXQ1__c.

But the error is that no records are being formed .

Any generic reason for records not being formed ?

Comment: Can you please add more of your code? Specifically all the code that relates to creating records - what you have here does not create records, and on it's own, won't update them either.

Comment: What do you mean with `no records are being formed`? Give more info.

Comment: as an aside, `mapCountryWiseAggr` should be named something like `countryToCountryWiseAggrMap` to be more meaningful (some folks like to name map as `CountryWiseAggrByCountry`)  Always good idea to identify the map key versus the map value in the variable name